# Using GAP Socket for communication. Compiler says PGPlugin.h not found

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to establish a socket connection using `GapSocket` and send some data (strings) to a tcp socket from a PhoneGap app to a computer with port 8888 opened.

I have included all dependencies:

- Both `asyncsocket.m` and `asynsocket.h` from `cocoaasyncsocket`
- Both `GapSocketCommand.m` and `GapSocketCommand.h` from `GapSocket`
- Included `GapSocket.js` and referenced the js file from `index.html` under `www` folder.

When I compile it, it says `PGPlugin.h` not found, and I am really unable to find this header file.

How can I solve it? I am using the latest PhoneGap version 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `PGPlugin.h` was used in previous versions of Phonegap / Cordova. For newer versions, they replaced it with `CDVPlugin.h`.

A solution (well it's not really a solution but mostly a "trick" / "potential way to make it work"...) which could work for you would be to replace any references to `PGPlugin.h` with `CDVPlugin.h` (`<Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>`). This solution worked for some people; however, the problem is that you may encounter several dependencies linking to old references...

I suggest you to first check if there is a released version of `GapSocket` which has been ported to Cordova 2.1.1 before trying the above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Littm. Its compiling without any error now. but i got another problem.